# circular reference with data validation list in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to see if it is possible to choose an item from a data validation list in either sheet 2 or 3 or 4, cell E2 to change automatically. Meaning i want the cell E2 in each of these sheets linked with each other, so if i change any one of them the other has to show the new value. The list itself is in sheet 1.

I also would like to extend this macro from just cell E2 to a range of cells (E2 to E300).

The problem i have now is if i use the code, it also changes the value of cell E2 in sheet 1. I have the code copied to modules in sheets 2, 3 4 and not in module of sheet 1.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    If Target.Address = "$E$2" Then
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            If Not ws.Name = Me.Name And Not ws.Name = "Sheet1" Then
                If Not ws.Range(Target.Address) = Me.Range(Target.Address) Then
                    ws.Range(Target.Address) = Me.Range(Target.Address)
                End If
            End If
        Next ws
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You should turn off events while changing the cells on the other sheets. BTW it might be more efficient to handle this as a workbook-level event so you only have one copy of the code in the workbook code module instead of a copy in each worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. You cna handle an unique sub from `Worksheet_Change` event

I made up this code in that event on each worksheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
UPDATE_E_VALUES ActiveSheet, Target
End Sub
```

And the code in a module of sub `UPDATE_E_VALUES` is:

```
Public Sub UPDATE_E_VALUES(ByVal vThisWK As Worksheet, ByVal vThisCell As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If vThisCell.Row >= 2 And vThisCell.Row <= 300 And vThisCell.Column = 5 Then 'check if cell is in range E2:E300
    Select Case vThisWK.Name
        Case "Sheet1"
            'we do nothing
        Case "Sheet5"
            'we do nothing
        Case Else
            'we update all E cells with same address
            With ThisWorkbook
                .Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(vThisCell.Address).Value = vThisCell.Value
                .Worksheets("Sheet3").Range(vThisCell.Address).Value = vThisCell.Value
                .Worksheets("Sheet4").Range(vThisCell.Address).Value = vThisCell.Value
            End With
    End Select
    With ThisWorkbook
        .Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(vThisCell.Address).Value = vThisCell.Value
    End With

End If

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Hope you can adapt this to your needs. You can add/remove extra lines where you want sheets to be affected or not